# Using .html_safe in an each loop

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I've been running into issues with using `.html_safe` within `.each` loops. Here is how I may have something set up...

```
class Players < ApplicationController::Base
  def index
    @players = Players.all
  end
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
  <div>
    <%= player.stat_code.html_safe %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now the `stat_code` would be a long HTML chunk of code... (I don't have an example for this case) But it's HTML.

Using the `.html_safe` does not seem to do anything while it's in a `.each` loop. Why does nothing happen and what other solution would you recommend?

Note: I also read that using `.html_safe` is bad! For this particular case I don't care.

Comment: I think I accomplished my problem using `sanitize` instead of `html_safe`....

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish my issue by setting up the view with `sanitize` instead of `.html_safe` like so...

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
  <div>
    <%= sanitize player.stat_code %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```